# IF statement with RC in vba gives compile error, why?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am currently working on a small VBA code that needs to compare a piece of string. If I would type this directly into excel I would do following:

```
=IF(C14 = "ABC",1,0)
```

Now, since this is a VBA code, it needs to do this as a relative reference. Instead it would look something like this:

```
=IF(RC[-5] = "ABC",1,0)
```

**Problem: Now, the latter `IF` statement gives a compile error - why so?**

If I where to type in

```
  =IF(RC[-5] = 2,1,0)
```

This does not give any compile error. So it appears that the String comparisment gives me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vba code try this

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=""ABC"",1,0)"
```

**Followup from comments.**

> Howcome the double "" is needed? – SteewDK 3 mins ago

We need the extra `"` to encompass the double quotes to pass it as a string. You could use `Chr(34)` as well. For example

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]=" & Chr(34) & "ABC" & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"
```

BTW if you do not want to use a formula then you can use `OFFSET` as well

For example

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0,-5).Value = "ABC" Then _
ActiveCell.Value = 1 Else ActiveCell.Value = 0
```

Comment: @SteewDK: I have Updated my answer :). You might have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, or you can also rewrite `IF` statement as follows: `ActiveCell.Value=IIF(ActiveCell.Offset(0,-5).Value = "ABC",1,0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a off topic question: 
Assumeing I have some relative reference, lets denote this RC[-5] - would I then be able to parse this relative reference to a function? If yes, what would the function need to be? 
E.g. Function abc(a As Range) as Double
if a = "abc" then
abc = 1
End Function
Would something like that be possible?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you explain it a bit? Edit: If it is an entirely new question, then I would recommend asking a new question with appropriate description + example?